# How do I create a Permission set through script/eclipse or mavensmate ?

Tags: community, profile, permission-sets, force.com-ide

I want to create 66 permission sets in the sandbox through eclipse or another IDE can you please suggest me how i do this through script. please help me > ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a permission set using APEX.

See [ObjectPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectpermissions.htm) and [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) object for a reference.

Example:

```
PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
ps.Name='TestPermissionSet';
ps.label='TestPermissionSet';
insert ps;

//insert Object permission for Idea
ObjectPermissions op = new ObjectPermissions();
op.parentId = ps.Id;
op.SobjectType = 'Idea';
op.PermissionsCreate = true;
op.PermissionsRead = true;
insert op;
```